# Illustrator: Using Variables for Dimensions

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have multiple objects on my canvas that all have the same dimension. Is there a way to bind the dimension of all objects to a variable, so I can change the dimension of all objects by simply changing one variable?

Comment: If they are the same object then yes. If not then not really. Illustrator does not really have a scene graph like this.

Comment: Please provide more details. Perhaps screenshots before and after the wanted transformation. There might be a solution and there might not depending on what you are trying to achieve. Some things might even be easier in InDesign.